# Getting the numeric value of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the numeric value of any string in javascript. How would I go about this?

Ex: string = "what is my numeric value"

I am wanting the numeric value of string?

Thanks....

Comment: `+str` or `parseInt(str, 10)` or `Number(str)`, and don't forget about `NaN` which you will get for invalid numbers

Comment: Are you looking for if a string has numerals IN it, or what the character count is of the string?

Comment: I think you have to expand on the "numeric value of string" part.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an integer version of a string that contains a number, then like so:

```
var string = '3';
var stringNum = parseInt( string ); // 3
```

If you're looking for the number of characters in a string, then:

```
var string = 'hello test one two';
var stringLength = string.length; // 18
```

EDIT: One more thing to call out. If you run `parseInt()` that isn't a number, you'll get `NaN` as a result.

Comment: I like this but in the interest of being a complete answer I created a fiddle that expands on this a little bit. It checks if the string is a number. If not it defaults to 0.   http://jsfiddle.net/0gj5v891/

Answer (score 1):

As it's not exactly clear what you want, here is a function that gives you an *Array* of the *char codes* of the string

```
function strToCharCode(str) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(str, function(e){return e.charCodeAt(0);});
}

strToCharCode("what is my numeric value");
/*
[
    119, 104,  97, 116,  32, 105, 115,  32,
    109, 121,  32, 110, 117, 109, 101, 114,
    105,  99,  32, 118,  97, 108, 117, 101
]
*/
```

Please note that internally *JavaScript* uses *UCS-2*, which is similar to *UTF-16*, using 16-bit encoding (not 8 bit) so non-latin characters may have values up to `65535`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking he wants a numeric value of a String so that he can later change it back into the same word

maybe from String to Binary to Numeric and vice-versa ?